# SQL Language Injection detection within JavaScript code in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I have a project that uses both server side PHP and server side JavaScript. (nodejs, using ES6 and transpiling correctly with Babel etc). Because of the inclusion of PHP, I'm using PhpStorm instead of WebStorm for the IDE.

PhpStorm correctly automatically detects SQL strings inside my PHP code and gives me the appropriate syntax coloring, code completion, etc, but does not detect any SQL strings inside my JavaScript.

Obviously, I can tell PhpStorm that a specific string is SQL by using the

```
// language=PostgreSQL
```

language injection comment found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-language-injections.html#ways

But it'd be nice to not have to do that every time. I know that PhpStorm has a way to create custom language injections, but I'm afraid I don't really understand the syntax necessary to create them. It seems to use something called brics, and I have no idea what that is. The JetBrains docs don't seem to be particularly helpful, although if I've missed something, please feel free to point it out.

I took a quick look in WebStorm but it seems WebStorm hasn't caught up with the whole serverside JavaScript revolution fully and JetBrains don't realize that people might want to write SQL in their JavaScript.

Can anyone walk me through how to set up a custom Language Injection setting within PhpStorm to have it detect SQL inside a JavaScript string? Is it even possible?

Comment: AFAIK it's not really possible -- at very least based on default Language Injection rules that available by default. Lots of language injection rules in JavaScript (e.g. jQuery's `$()` etc) are actually hardcoded (not available for customisation or turning off via GUI). Right now injection via comment is possibly the best way.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was wondering if it was possible. I'll make a post on their suggestion board for it to be added. I'd think that with the increase in server-side javascript, more and more JS is coded to talk directly to a database, something that has historically never really been a thing.

Comment: I do not want to say that it is 100% not possible ... but considering that there are a lots of injection places in JavaScript code that cannot be turned off (e.g. HTML in plain string; because there are no rules for them in GUI) it's very possible outcome in current version. Sure, there is one bundled rule named "HTML5 SQL Database (SQLite)" which has `+ jsLiteralExpression().and(jsArgument("executeSql", 0))` as content ... but it's not based on JS strings (rather on function parameter name or method name) as compared to what is offered for PHP.

Comment: I've also tried to replicate existing SQL injections available in PHP to wotk in JS context .. and despite the fact that the same works in PHP ... it does nothing in JS context (either it does not match .. or not possible). So yeah -- making a Issue Tracker ticket in WebStorm project (parent for JS related issues) is the best idea I would say -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: That's existing ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10122 -- there is a solution (worked for the guy back in 2013) ... but it does not seem to do anything in latest 2017.2.x version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10122#comment=27-633919

Comment: Ah. Yes. I thought it worked... but then it didn't.